# GridView does not refresh changes to items when using LayoutAwarePage.DefaultViewModel

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8, viewmodel, dependency-properties

In a "Blank App" (Visual C#, Windows Store), I create a new "Grouped Items Page", then declare a `MyItemViewModel` class deriving from `DependencyObject` with a Dependency Property for a `String Title`.

This is the page's LoadState method:

```
protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = this.items;
    this.items.Add(new MyItemViewModel { Title = "My Title" });

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.items.First().Title += ".";
    }
}
```

The expectation is that dots appear after the item's title every second. The actual output is simply "My Title" and nothing else happens.

By adding the following *unreferenced* dependency property the dots will then appear:

```
public MyItemViewModel blah
{
    get { return (MyItemViewModel)GetValue(blahProperty); }
    set { SetValue(blahProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty blahProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("blah", typeof(MyItemViewModel), typeof(GroupedItemsPage1), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Why does the GridView only refresh the Title property of the item view model when there is an unused dependency property with the same type?

Do view model classes always have to be explicitly declared as a dependency property somewhere in an app at least once?

Comment: I might misunderstand what you are trying to do, but can you use INotifyPropertyChanged and call PropertyChanged when Title is updated in this case?

Comment: It might be my misunderstanding, but I was expecting that the the DependencyProperty would take care of notifications, especially since it works when the dummy property is declared.

Comment: DependencyObject is usually inherited by UIElement (e.g., Grid, TextBlock, etc.), and their properties are DependencyProperty which allows, for example, Binding. A ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of inherit from DependencyObject. If you look at sample templates like GridApp, you will see that BindableBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I switched from using DependencyObject to INotifyPropertyChanged, and it works. I guess I do not completely understand the behavior of DependencyObject, but it makes sense that view models should not be DependencyObjects if they are not views. Do you want to submit this as the answer?

Comment: I just posted my comment as an answer with some links. Glad to know that it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.aspx) is usually inherited by [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) (e.g., Grid, TextBlock, etc.), and their properties are [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700353.aspx) which allows, for example, Binding.

A ViewModel should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) instead of inherit from DependencyObject. If you look at sample templates like GridApp, you will see that BindableBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged.